# Show All Dropdown options when typeahead input field is empty and select multiple tags using typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using bootstrap tags-input plugin and type-ahead.

I want both of them to work together i.e. if the input field is empty show whole drop-down and if type-ahead is used it should select multiple options like tags-input.

How can I achieve this?

Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7yDk829M3wavyn1oJoAE?p=preview is the link that shows what i require. But  i am not able to do it using this code.

Comment: A bit old question, but I found out that in your example you can pass the option `showHintOnFocus: true` in your `typeahead` object. So, you don't have to add a button for it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$('#device').tagsinput({ 
   typeahead: {
      source:  ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'Wyoming'],
     autoSelect: false,
     items : 1000,
     minLength : 0
   }
});
```

The key difference is using "typeahead" instead of "typeaheadjs" in your tagsinput options.
These guys explain it better. https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/